# Segmentation Fault when using glmnet mex with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, segmentation-fault, mex

My jobs have been suffering due to segmentation faults when calling glmnet (downloaded from here:[http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet_matlab/download.html](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/glmnet_matlab/download.html)) from my MATLAB code. I call the glmnet routine thousands of times. I have noticed the following peculiarities about the problem occurence:

1. The problem is more frequent when the size of my input matrices are larger.
2. I use both gaussian and poisson distribution in separate jobs, and I notice that the problem is more frequent when fitting the Poisson distribution (which also takes usually longer to converge, so might involve more loops internally?)
   Since there haven't been reports of segmentation faults for the R version for these two distributions, my suspicion is that the problem, likely a memory leak, might lie in the mex interface rather than the core glmnet Fortran code, which I am pasting below. Any insights into where a memory leak might be happening is greatly appreciated! Apologies for the lengthy code dump.

Thanks!

```
      subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)
C-----------------------------------------------------------------------

      mwpointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      mwpointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix, mxGetPr, mxCreateNumericArray
      integer nlhs, nrhs
      mwsize mxGetM, mxGetN, mxGetNzmax
      integer mxIsNumeric
      integer mxIsSparse
      
C-----------------------------------------------------------------------

C     Input
      real parm,flmin,thr, intr
      integer ka,no,ni,nr,nc,ne,nx,nlam,isd,maxit,kopt,isparse,nnz,jsd
      real, dimension (:), allocatable :: x,y,w,vp,ulam,cl,sr,xs,o,d,
     $     flog,a
      integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: ix,jx,jd,irs,jcs

      mwpointer pr

C     Output
      integer lmu,nlp,jerr
      real dev0
      real, dimension (:), allocatable :: a0,ca,alm,dev,rsq
      integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: ia,nin

C     Temporary      
      mwpointer temp_pr
      mwsize temp_m, temp_n, temp_nzmax, dims(3)
      integer task,i

C     For internal parameters
      real fdev, devmax, eps, big, pmin, prec, exmx
      integer mnlam, mxit
      
C     Check for proper number of arguments.
      if (nrhs .eq. 0) then
         task = -1;
      else
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,task,1)
      endif

C     Get input

      if (task .eq. -1) then
         call get_int_parms(fdev,eps,big,mnlam,devmax,pmin,exmx)
         call get_bnorm(prec,mxit)

         plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))
         call putreal(fdev,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(2) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(2))
         call putreal(devmax,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(3) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(3))
         call putreal(eps,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(4) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(4))
         call putreal(big,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(5) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(5))
         call putinteger(mnlam,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(6) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(6))
         call putreal(pmin,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(7) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(7))
         call putreal(exmx,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(8) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(8))
         call putreal(prec,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(9) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(9))
         call putinteger(mxit,temp_pr,1)

         return   
      endif 
      
      if (task .eq. 0) then
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(2))
         call getreal(temp_pr,fdev,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(3))
         call getreal(temp_pr,devmax,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(4))
         call getreal(temp_pr,eps,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(5))
         call getreal(temp_pr,big,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(6))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,mnlam,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(7))
         call getreal(temp_pr,pmin,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(8))
         call getreal(temp_pr,exmx,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(9))
         call getreal(temp_pr,prec,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(10))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,mxit,1)

         call chg_fract_dev(fdev)
         call chg_dev_max(devmax)
         call chg_min_flmin(eps)
         call chg_big(big)
         call chg_min_lambdas(mnlam)
         call chg_min_null_prob(pmin)
         call chg_max_exp(exmx)
         call chg_bnorm(prec, mxit)

         return
      endif

c$$$  -----------------Gaussian--------------------  
c$$$  ---input---   
      
      if (task .eq. 10 .or. task .eq. 11) then
         if (task .eq. 11) then
            temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(3))
            temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(3))
            no = temp_m
            temp_n = mxGetN(prhs(3))
            ni = temp_n
            allocate(x(1:no*ni))
            call getreal(temp_pr,x,no*ni)
            
         else
            temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(4))
            no = temp_m

            temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(3))
            temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(3))
            nnz = temp_m
            allocate(xs(1:nnz))
            call getreal(temp_pr,xs,nnz)

            temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(19))
            allocate(irs(1:nnz))
            call getinteger(temp_pr,irs,nnz) 

            temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(20))
            temp_n = mxGetM(prhs(20))
            ni = temp_n - 1
            allocate(jcs(1:(ni+1)))
            call getinteger(temp_pr,jcs,(ni+1)) 
         endif

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(2))
         call getreal(temp_pr,parm,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(4))
         allocate(y(1:no))
         call getreal(temp_pr,y,no)
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(5))
         temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(5))
         temp_n = mxGetN(prhs(5))
         allocate(jd(temp_m*temp_n))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,jd,temp_m*temp_n)     
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(6))
         allocate(vp(1:ni))
         call getreal(temp_pr,vp,ni)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(7))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,ne,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(8))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,nx,1)
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(9))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,nlam,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(10))
         call getreal(temp_pr,flmin,1)     
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(11))
         temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(11))
         temp_n = mxGetN(prhs(11))
         allocate(ulam(1:temp_m * temp_n))
         call getreal(temp_pr,ulam,temp_m * temp_n)
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(12))
         call getreal(temp_pr,thr,1)
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(13))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,isd,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(14))
         allocate(w(1:no))
         call getreal(temp_pr,w,no)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(15))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,ka,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(16))
         allocate(cl(1:2*ni))
         call getreal(temp_pr,cl,2*ni)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(17))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,intr,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(18))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,maxit,1)       

c$$$  ---prepare output---

         allocate(ia(1:nx))
         call zerointeger(ia,nx)
         allocate(nin(1:nlam))
         call zerointeger(nin,nlam)
         allocate(alm(1:nlam))
         call zeroreal(alm,nlam)
         allocate(a0(1:nlam))
         call zeroreal(a0,nlam)         
         allocate(ca(1:nx*nlam))
         call zeroreal(ca,nx*nlam)
         allocate(rsq(1:nlam))
         call zeroreal(rsq,nlam)


c$$$  ---computation----

         if (task .eq. 11) then    
            call elnet(ka,parm,no,ni,x,y,w,jd,vp,cl,ne,nx,nlam,flmin,
     $           ulam,thr,isd,intr,maxit,lmu,a0,ca,ia,nin,rsq,alm,
     $           nlp,jerr)
         else
            call spelnet(ka,parm,no,ni,xs,jcs,irs,y,w,jd,vp,cl,ne,nx,
     $           nlam,flmin,ulam,thr,isd,intr,maxit,lmu,a0,ca,ia,nin,
     $           rsq,alm,nlp,jerr)
         endif

c$$$  ----output-----

         plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))
         call putinteger(lmu,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(4) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nx,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(4))
         call putinteger(ia,temp_pr,nx)
         
         plhs(5) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(lmu,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(5))
         call putinteger(nin,temp_pr,lmu)
         
         plhs(7) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(lmu,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(7))
         call putreal(alm,temp_pr,lmu)
         
         plhs(8) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(8))
         call putinteger(nlp,temp_pr,1)
         
         plhs(9) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(9))
         call putinteger(jerr,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(2) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(lmu,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(2))
         call putreal(a0,temp_pr,lmu)   
         
         plhs(3) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nx,lmu,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(3))
         call putreal(ca,temp_pr,nx*lmu)  
         
         plhs(6) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(lmu,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(6))
         call putreal(rsq,temp_pr,lmu)  

         deallocate(y)
         deallocate(jd)
         deallocate(vp)
         deallocate(ulam)
         deallocate(a0)
         deallocate(ca)
         deallocate(ia)
         deallocate(nin)
         deallocate(alm)
         deallocate(w)
         deallocate(rsq)
         deallocate(cl)
         
         if (task .eq. 11) then
            deallocate(x)
         else
            deallocate(xs)
            deallocate(irs)
            deallocate(jcs)  
         endif
         return
      endif      
c$$$  --------------end of Gaussian---------------------------
c$$$  ---------------Poisson--------------------------
c$$$  ---input---   
      
      if (task .eq. 50 .or. task .eq. 51) then
         if (task .eq. 51) then
            temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(3))
            temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(3))
            no = temp_m
            temp_n = mxGetN(prhs(3))
            ni = temp_n
            allocate(x(1:no*ni))
            call getreal(temp_pr,x,no*ni)
            
         else
            temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(4))
            no = temp_m

            temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(3))
            temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(3))
            nnz = temp_m
            allocate(xs(1:nnz))
            call getreal(temp_pr,xs,nnz)

            temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(19))
            allocate(irs(1:nnz))
            call getinteger(temp_pr,irs,nnz) 

            temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(20))
            temp_n = mxGetM(prhs(20))
            ni = temp_n - 1
            allocate(jcs(1:(ni+1)))
            call getinteger(temp_pr,jcs,(ni+1)) 
         endif

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(2))
         call getreal(temp_pr,parm,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(4))
         allocate(y(1:no))
         call getreal(temp_pr,y,no)
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(5))
         temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(5))
         temp_n = mxGetN(prhs(5))
         allocate(jd(temp_m*temp_n))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,jd,temp_m*temp_n)     
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(6))
         allocate(vp(1:ni))
         call getreal(temp_pr,vp,ni)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(7))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,ne,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(8))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,nx,1)
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(9))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,nlam,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(10))
         call getreal(temp_pr,flmin,1)     
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(11))
         temp_m = mxGetM(prhs(11))
         temp_n = mxGetN(prhs(11))
         allocate(ulam(1:temp_m * temp_n))
         call getreal(temp_pr,ulam,temp_m * temp_n)
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(12))
         call getreal(temp_pr,thr,1)
         
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(13))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,isd,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(14))
         allocate(w(1:no))
         call getreal(temp_pr,w,no)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(15))
         allocate(cl(1:2*ni))
         call getreal(temp_pr,cl,2*ni)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(16))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,intr,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(17))
         call getinteger(temp_pr,maxit,1)

         temp_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(18))
         allocate(o(1:no))
         call getreal(temp_pr,o,no)

c$$$  ---prepare output---

         allocate(ia(1:nx))
         call zerointeger(ia,nx)
         allocate(nin(1:nlam))
         call zerointeger(nin,nlam)
         allocate(alm(1:nlam))
         call zeroreal(alm,nlam)
         allocate(a0(1:nlam))
         call zeroreal(a0,nlam)
         allocate(ca(1:nx*nlam))
         call zeroreal(ca,nx*nlam)
         allocate(dev(1:nlam))
         call zeroreal(dev,nlam)

c$$$  ---computation----

         if (task .eq. 51) then    
            call fishnet(parm,no,ni,x,y,o,w,jd,vp,cl,ne,nx,nlam,flmin,
     $           ulam,thr,isd,intr,maxit,lmu,a0,ca,ia,nin,dev0,dev,alm,
     $           nlp,jerr)
         else
            call spfishnet(parm,no,ni,xs,jcs,irs,y,o,w,jd,vp,cl,ne,nx,
     $           nlam,flmin,ulam,thr,isd,intr,maxit,lmu,a0,ca,ia,
     $           nin,dev0,dev,alm,nlp,jerr)
         endif

c$$$  ----output-----

         plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))
         call putinteger(lmu,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(4) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nx,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(4))
         call putinteger(ia,temp_pr,nx)
         
         plhs(5) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(lmu,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(5))
         call putinteger(nin,temp_pr,lmu)
         
         plhs(7) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(lmu,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(7))
         call putreal(alm,temp_pr,lmu)
         
         plhs(8) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(8))
         call putinteger(nlp,temp_pr,1)
         
         plhs(9) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(9))
         call putinteger(jerr,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(2) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(lmu,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(2))
         call putreal(a0,temp_pr,lmu)

         plhs(3) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nx,lmu,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(3))
         call putreal(ca,temp_pr,nx*lmu)
         
         plhs(6) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(lmu,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(6))
         call putreal(dev,temp_pr,lmu)

         plhs(10) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(10))
         call putreal(dev0,temp_pr,1)

         plhs(11) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(no,1,0)
         temp_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(11))
         call putreal(o,temp_pr,no)

         deallocate(y)
         deallocate(jd)
         deallocate(vp)
         deallocate(ulam)
         deallocate(a0)
         deallocate(ca)
         deallocate(ia)
         deallocate(nin)
         deallocate(alm)
         deallocate(cl)
         deallocate(o)
         deallocate(dev)
         
         if (task .eq. 51) then
            deallocate(x)
         else
            deallocate(xs)
            deallocate(irs)
            deallocate(jcs)  
         endif
         return
      endif

c$$$  --------------------end of Poisson------------------

      return
      end

C     End of subroutine mexFunction
      
      subroutine real8toreal(x, y, size)
      integer size
      real*8 x(size)
      real y(size)
      do 10 i=1,size
         y(i)= x(i)
 10   continue
      return
      end

      subroutine realtoreal8(x, y, size)
      integer size
      real x(size)
      real*8 y(size)
      do 20 i=1,size
         y(i)= x(i)
 20   continue
      return
      end
      
      subroutine real8tointeger(x, y, size)
      integer size
      real*8 x(size)
      integer y(size)
      do 30 i=1,size
         y(i)= x(i)
 30   continue
      return
      end
      
      subroutine integertoreal8(x, y, size)
      integer size
      integer x(size)
      real*8 y(size)
      do 40 i=1,size
         y(i)= x(i)
 40   continue
      return
      end
      
      subroutine getreal(pr,x,size)
      mwpointer pr
      integer size
      real x(size)
      real*8, dimension (:), allocatable :: temp
      allocate(temp(1:size))
      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(pr,temp,size)
      call real8toreal(temp,x,size)
      deallocate(temp)      
      return
      end
      
      subroutine getinteger(pr,x,size)
      mwpointer pr
      integer size
      integer x(size)
      real*8, dimension (:), allocatable :: temp
      allocate(temp(1:size))
      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(pr,temp,size)
      call real8tointeger(temp,x,size)
      deallocate(temp)      
      return
      end      
      
      subroutine putreal(x,pr,size)
      mwpointer pr
      integer size
      real x(size)
      real*8, dimension (:), allocatable :: temp
      allocate(temp(1:size))
      call realtoreal8(x,temp,size)
      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(temp,pr,size)
      deallocate(temp)      
      return
      end
      
      subroutine putinteger(x,pr,size)
      mwpointer pr
      integer size
      integer x(size)
      real*8, dimension (:), allocatable :: temp
      allocate(temp(1:size))
      call integertoreal8(x,temp,size)
      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(temp,pr,size)
      deallocate(temp)      
      return
      end            
      
      subroutine zeroreal(x,size)
      integer size
      real x(size)
      do 90 i=1,size
         x(i) = 0
 90   continue     
      return 
      end
      
      subroutine zerointeger(x,size)
      integer size
      integer x(size)
      do 100 i=1,size
         x(i) = 0
 100  continue
      return
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is clean up the MATLAB API interface stuff.  Remember that in Fortran you do not get automatic type promotion in function/subroutine argument lists like you do in C/C++.  So it is important to get the signatures exact.  You should NEVER be passing literal integers to MATLAB API functions.  You should be passing variables that are typed exactly as the API specifies to ensure that there is not a mismatch. E.g., take this code:

```
  subroutine getreal(pr,x,size)
  mwpointer pr
  integer size
  real x(size)
  real*8, dimension (:), allocatable :: temp
  allocate(temp(1:size))
  call mxCopyPtrToReal8(pr,temp,size)
  call real8toreal(temp,x,size)
  deallocate(temp)      
  return
  end
```

The signature for mxCopyPtrToReal8 in the API is:

```
  subroutine mxCopyPtrToReal8(px, y, n)
  mwPointer px
  real*8 y(n)
  mwSize n
```

So you have a potential mismatch because the default Fortran integer might not match mwSize.  Also, size is the name of a Fortran instrinsic function, so a different name for your variable would probably be more appropriate.
I would change that subroutine to:

```
  subroutine getreal(pr,x,sizex)
  mwpointer pr
  mwSize sizex
  real x(sizex)
  real*8, dimension (:), allocatable :: temp
  allocate(temp(1:sizex))
  call mxCopyPtrToReal8(pr,temp,sizex)
  call real8toreal(temp,x,sizex)
  deallocate(temp)      
  return
  end
```

Now you are ensured that sizex is the appropriate type.  You would also need to change the types of the variables in the calling routine.

(SIDE NOTE: Actually, I wouldn't do any of what you are doing ... I would simply write a loop to copy the values directly from the mxArray into your real array without extra copies and memory allocation/deallocation)

Another example is this:

```
  integer ...,nx,...
      :
  integer lmu,...
       :
     plhs(3) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nx,lmu,0)
```

Should be replaced with:

```
  mwSize nx, lmu
  integer*4 :: ComplexFlag = 0
       :
     plhs(3) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nx,lmu,ComplexFlag)
```

And, frankly, you have lots of assignment loops that can be replace by simple statements.  E.g.,

```
  call real8toreal(temp,x,sizex)
```

can be replaced with:

```
  x = temp
```

And this:

```
 allocate(ia(1:nx))
 call zerointeger(ia,nx)
 allocate(nin(1:nlam))
 call zerointeger(nin,nlam)
 allocate(alm(1:nlam))
 call zeroreal(alm,nlam)
 allocate(a0(1:nlam))
 call zeroreal(a0,nlam)
 allocate(ca(1:nx*nlam))
 call zeroreal(ca,nx*nlam)
 allocate(dev(1:nlam))
 call zeroreal(dev,nlam)
```

can be replaced with this:

```
 allocate(ia(1:nx))
 ia = 0
 allocate(nin(1:nlam))
 nin = 0
 allocate(alm(1:nlam))
 alm = 0.0
 allocate(a0(1:nlam))
 a0 = 0.0
 allocate(ca(1:nx*nlam))
 ca = 0.0
 allocate(dev(1:nlam))
 dev = 0.0
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks! That was really insightful. This wasn't my own code, and I got it through the glmnet package page. I was not quite sure how to debug the code in the state it was in, but your suggestions give me a really good direction to start cleaning up the code and debugging.